# Segfault no fwrite. Por quê?

Tags: c

Por que esse programa está dando *segfault*?

```
struct{
    int matricula;
    char nome[50];
}Aluno;


int main(){

    FILE *arq;

    if((fopen("alunos.txt", "w")) == NULL){
        printf("Nao foi possivel abrir o arquivo.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    do{
        printf("Matricula: ");
        scanf("%d", &Aluno.matricula);

        if(Aluno.matricula == 0){
            break;
        }

        printf("Nome: ");
        scanf("%s", Aluno.nome);

     // fwrite(&Aluno, sizeof(Aluno), 1, arq);

        // printf("%d %s\n", Aluno.matricula ,Aluno.nome);
        fwrite(&Aluno, sizeof(Aluno), 1, arq);

    }while(1);

    fclose(arq);

    return 0;
}
```

Já tentei usar o Dev-C++ e o compilador do bash, mas o erro persiste.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Olhe isso:

```
    FILE *arq;

    if((fopen("alunos.txt", "w")) == NULL){
```

O resultado do `fopen` não está sendo atribuído à `arq`. Assim sendo, a variável `arq` vai ficar com lixo.

O que você queria era isso:

```
    FILE *arq = fopen("alunos.txt", "w");

    if (arq == NULL) {
```

Comment: vlw. falta de atenção aqui.